# multiple filters in a single iteration

Tags: filter, clojure, functional-programming

Suppose I have a list of tuples like so:

```
[["type_2" "val_x"] ["type_1" "val_y"] ["type_1" "val_z"]]
```

I'd like to filter them, so that I have two separate collections like this:

```
[["type_2" "val_x"]] 

[["type_1" "val_y"] ["type_1" "val_z"]]
```

I can run filter twice. I'm wondering if it's possible to achieve the same result in a single iteration with functional programming?

This is the desired interface:

```
(multiple-filter predicate_fn_1 predicate_fn_2 coll)
```

Comment: `(vals (group-by first [["type_2" "val_x"] ["type_1" "val_y"] ["type_1" "val_z"]]))` should do what you want

Comment: @m33lky could you please move the code blocks to their own lines and add four spaces at the start of the line to make them code blocks, then remove the ` ` from around them. I normally fix these formatting problems but there is a problem with SO where I cannot edit questions with other pending edits so I cannot fix this formatting for you.

Comment: @ArthurUlfeldt Placed everything in code blocks rather than ticks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

while `(vals (group-by first...` would work ok in your case, it is not universal. Here is a variant (one of many possible ones) of applying multiple filters:

```
(defn classify [items & preds]
  (loop [[x & xs :as items] items
         res (repeat (count preds) [])]
    (if (empty? items)
      res
      (recur xs 
             (mapv #(if (% x) (conj %2 x) %2) preds res)))))
```

in repl:

```
user> (classify [[:a 10] [:a 20] [:b 30] [:d 2] [:c 40] [:d 1]]
                #(= (first %) :a)
                #(= (first %) :b)
                #(= (first %) :d))
[[[:a 10] [:a 20]] [[:b 30]] [[:d 2] [:d 1]]]
```

or the same with reduce:

```
(defn classify [items & preds]
  (reduce (fn [res x] (mapv #(if (% x) (conj %2 x) %2) preds res))
          (repeat (count preds) [])
          items))
```

Comment: You could also write `(apply classify [[:a 10] [:a 20] [:b 30] [:d 2] [:c 40] [:d 1]] (map #(comp #{%} first) [:a :b :d]))`.

Comment: @SamEstep Why not add it as a separate answer?

Comment: @m33lky Because my comment is only a note about usage of the function, and has nothing to do with the implementation. However, I do also believe that the implementation can be improved, so I have added my own answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

The `classify` function by @leetwinski fails to satisfy your desired interface; as an example, here is a compliant implementation:

```
(defn multiple-filter [& preds-and-coll]
  (let [[preds coll] ((juxt drop-last last) preds-and-coll)]
    (mapv #(filterv % coll) preds)))
```

Example:

```
(multiple-filter (comp #{"type_1"} first)
                 (comp #{"type_2"} first)
                 [["type_2" "val_x"] ["type_1" "val_y"] ["type_1" "val_z"]])
;;=> [[["type_1" "val_y"] ["type_1" "val_z"]] [["type_2" "val_x"]]]
```

I haven't implemented this as a single iteration because that would complicate this answer and not affect the algorithmic complexity, but feel free to replace my implementation using `mapv` and `filterv` with @leetwinski's single-iteration implementation.

Comment: so in fact it is `(count preds)` passes over the collection? While the question (as i undefstood it, at least), was about multiple filters in one pass

Comment: @leetwinski Yes, I partially addressed that in my answer: in my implementation, the outer loop iterates over `preds` and the inner loop iterates over `coll`, whereas in your implementation, the outer loop iterates over `items` and the inner loop iterates over `preds`. It doesn't affect the algorithmic complexity, so I left it as-is, but it would be easy to swap in your implementation if necessary.

Comment: oh. you are right. I guess this one is better then.